# react-swiper is not re-rendered

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
function WorkSpace() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const edit = useSelector((state)=>(state.workSpace.edit));
    const currentMode = useSelector((state)=>(state.workSpace.currentMode));

    useEffect(()=>{
        const swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper').swiper;
        swiper.update();
    }, [edit])

    return(
        <div id="workWrapper">
            <Swiper
                style={{width:"100vw"}}
                slidesPerView={1}
                initialSlide={currentMode}
                onRealIndexChange={(swiper)=>{
                    switch(swiper.realIndex)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            dispatch(changeMode(mode.TODO));
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            dispatch(changeMode(mode.DIARY));
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            dispatch(changeMode(mode.GOAL));
                            break;
                    }
                }}
                onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
                touchRatio={edit?0:1}
                loop={true}
            >
                <SwiperSlide><ToDoList/></SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide><Diary/></SwiperSlide>
                <SwiperSlide><ToMyGoal/></SwiperSlide>
            </Swiper>
        </div>
    );
}
```

This is my code. I learned that when parent components get re-rendered, so does its child component. When I change 'edit' to false or true, WorkSpace component is re-rendered. I checked it by printing logs. but it seems like even though WorkSpace component gets re-rendered, the Swiper component does not.

When the 'edit' is true, the swiper must not be moved, so I set touchRatio to zero when 'edit' is true. But since the Swiper is not re-rendered, it is still slidable.

```
    useEffect(()=>{
        const swiper = document.querySelector('.swiper').swiper;
        swiper.update();
    }, [edit])
```

I tried to update swiper every time 'edit' changed, but it does not work.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to mess around with the DOM like you are doing in the useEffect().  What's the purpose for that?  The rules for React are pretty simple: a component will render when either: (1) a state value in the component is modified using the "set state function", or (2) its parent is rendered.  So there is no doubt that <Swiper> is being rendered when <WorkSpace> is being rendered. A "component" is simply a JS function.  "Render" simply means "the function is run".  So when <WorkSpace> is run, its `return` includes `<Swiper .... >`, which is JSX code for "run `Swiper( { .... } )`"

Comment: I'm using react-redux instead of useState to update the `edit` . can it be the source of problem? And I was just putting everything hoping if my code will work, so that DOM part was inserted with no much thinking. Sorry for that.

Comment: Your use of react-redux does not change at all from what I wrote...the tweak is that react-redux is maintaining state for your component.  The use of `useSelector()` essentially will cause <WorkSpace> to render whenever the selected value is changed via Redux.  Personally I have removed Redux from every one of my React projects. It is way overkill for 95+ % of the apps that use it, and that over-engineering leads us developers away from really understanding how our own apps work. If you're app is radically complex and large scale, it MIGHT make sense to use Redux. But rarely is that the case.